# Bootloader error installing Fedora

Tags: fedora, system-installation, grub2

I need a dual boot in my computer, Windows 7 and Fedora 17. I first installed Windows 7 and created the partition scheme during Windows install: 
- Partition 1: is a small partition automatically created by Windows when I create a partition (around 100MB)
- Partition 2: Partition where I will install Windows 7.
- Partition 3: Free space where I will install Fedora.

Everything works fine with Windows. Then I install Fedora, I create another partition for boot (around 500MB) and another logical partitions for swap and root (actually Fedora creates those partitions in the free space).

After all the installation the system shows a warning message: `There was an error installing the bootloader. The system may not be bootable`.

In fact, the system is not bootable. After the installation the computer always boots into Windows.

The weird thing is that I installed both systems several days ago and I had do reinstall both OSs, but not sure what is happening now.

Note: I also tried installing Grub2 with the live cd, but I have several problems with that, so may me is easier to solve the issue of the bootloader.

Comment: What sort of problems did you run into while installing `grub2` from LiveCD?

Comment: /usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib: line 53: 1830 Segmentation faul (core dumped) "${grub_probe}" -t fs "$path" > /dev/null 2>&1
Path '/boot/grub2' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.

Comment: Describe your hardware.

Comment: Segfaults could be from bugs, or from hardware problems. Have you tried memtest86?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only way I could fixed it was installing Fedora 16 and upgrading it to Fedora 17.

Answer (score 0):

What format is your boot partition?
If you're using GRUB 2, it should be *ext3* or *ext4*. Had a similar problem until I went through GRUB 2 documentation and found it no longer supported *ext2*.

Partiton 1 that Windows create is Windows bootloader. In this setup you'll need to install EasyBCD or another program to handle the choice of your OS

Comment: I'm using GRUB2 and ext4.

Comment: Then my suggestion holds no water :)
I would suppose it isn't related to this bug, depends on the version of Fedora - [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=809111)
You could try with just GRUB and see if that goes. Sorry I can't help you more. Only one more thing, is it LVM or standard installer partitions?

Comment: LVM partitions.